# Error when defining const for CollisionGroups in bevy

Tags: rust, bevy

I have an error when I try to define this `const` in a `character.rs` file:

```
const COLLISION_GROUPS_DEFAULT: CollisionGroups = CollisionGroups::new(
    Group::GROUP_2,
    Group::ALL - Group::GROUP_3
);
```

The error is:

```
error[E0277]: cannot subtract `bevy_rapier2d::geometry::Group` from `bevy_rapier2d::geometry::Group` in const contexts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `-` operator, you can use [`difference`](https://docs.rs/bevy_rapier2d/latest/bevy_rapier2d/geometry/struct.Group.html#method.difference), which is `const`:

```rust
const COLLISION_GROUPS_DEFAULT: CollisionGroups = CollisionGroups::new(
    Group::GROUP_2,
    Group::ALL.difference(Group::GROUP_3),
);
```